# Alternatives to ReplacementSpan in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, spannable, android-chips, text-styling

I know this question is very vague and doesn't probably have a single correct answer.
I just wanted to hear some input and create some content around advanced text styles in Compose. I hope it's fine.

Does anyone knows if there is a way to use Spans in compose?
I built a custom `MultiAutocompleteTextView` using the Views system that created chips using `ChipSpan(...): ImageSpan(...)`.

It looks something like this:

[image]

How would you handle this in Compose?
Any input will be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[InlineTextContent](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/text/InlineTextContent) might be what you are looking for. It uses `AnnotatedString` and placeholders and allows you to insert Composables inline with your text:

```kotlin
val text = buildAnnotatedString {
    appendInlineContent("chip1", "Acid")
}

val inlineContent = mapOf(
  "chip1" to InlineTextContent(
    Placeholder(
        width = 1.em, // calculate text width
        height = 1.em, // calculate text height
        placeholderVerticalAlign = PlaceholderVerticalAlign.AboveBaseline
    )
  ) {
     // call chip composable
  }
)

BasicText(text = text, inlineContent = inlineContent)
```

Comment: Hi, this would be a very nice idea if only it was possible to use it with TextFields without rewriting the entire thing from the ground up...! How would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to use with `Text`, `InlineTextContent` could be useful. But In case of `Textfield`, seems like it is yet to be implemented. Checkout the below feature request filed in [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/205878141).